# Process.Start doesn't start the process until main application is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, process.start

I have a WPF application. Clicking a button the application "starts" VLC using `Process.Start()` method. I tested this simple app on 2 computers:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ...
    private void RunVlcButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string applicationFile = "vlc.exe";
        MainWindow.RunProcess(applicationFile);
    }
    private static Process RunProcess(string applicationFile, string arguments = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Run process: {applicationFile} {arguments}");
        Process process = MainWindow.GetProcess(applicationFile, arguments);
        bool result = process.Start();
        if (!result)
            Console.WriteLine($"Can't start {applicationFile} {arguments}");
        return process;
    }
    private static Process GetProcess(string applicationFile, string arguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(applicationFile, arguments);Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process cmdProcess = new Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        return cmdProcess;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is nothing new or complicated. In the first computer works properly, **but in the other one VLC instances are started when main application is closed**.

The first computer is a Windows 10 Pro (build 16299) desktop.

The second computer is a Windows 10 Enterprise (build 10240) laptop.

Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Using Console.WriteLine() is not a great way to report critical errors in a WPF app.  Expecting ProcessStartInfo.RedirectXxx or CreateNoWindow to work on a GUI app is unwise.  And consider the simple explanation, it started just fine but you just can't see it.  Not until you close your window so now can see the VLC window.

Comment: Removing `RedirectXxx` or `CreateNoWindow` lines works fine! But I don't know why the problem happens with VLC, if I set `applicationFile = "notepad";` the notepad window is showed properly.